# How to label a Python package as version 3 only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

What do I have to do to make PyPI identify my package as working on Python 3 only?

Comment: related: [Is there a standard way to declare old python versions unsupported?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26437467/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You give it a [trove classifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers):

```
Programming Language :: Python :: 3
```

and leave out the Python 2 classifiers.

If you want to prevent your package from being installed on Python 2 systems anyway, you can simply exit the `setup.py` script after detecting the version:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    sys.stderr.write('Requires Python 3 or up\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Yikes...wouldn't it be better to raise an exception?  I guess that makes a bit of sense because, if you don't have python 3, what are you going to do?

Comment: @DavidSanders: this *does* raise an exception; `SystemExit`.